# What is the diference between angular declaration #myVariable and html id="myVariable"

Tags: html, angular

I need to create some automated testing tags for an angular web application. Basically, I intend to create a bunch of html ids for the components of interest in my unit test. What would be best practice for this activity? Does the angular template syntax `<html-tag #variable ...` work in the same way as `<html-tag id="variable" ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#variable` is used for creating [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) - and will not be available at run time when HTML is rendered.  You are better off using `id="variable"` to identify HTML elements in your tests.

Comment: it's not better, are two differents things and there are using to differents functions

Answer (score 0):

The `<html-tag #variable` pick up the reference to HtmlElement or superior. It can be marked on the property [exportAs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportAs)

The `<html-tag id="variable"` attribute represents the element's identifier, reflecting the [id global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)